# mysql : Need to short a query

Tags: mysql, if-statement, sum, group-concat

I have the query, which is giving correct result, but, it is having inner queries, having same conditions repeated. I have tried to short the length of the query as possible from my end.

Can anybody help me to reduce the complexity of the query, as it is taking 12 minutes to get the result in server, which may cause many issues in future.

The issue is that, same conditions are repeated, and the query is using inner query in it.

Query using these mysql parameters:-

**sum,if,GROUP_CONCAT** in it.

query:-

```
select 
sum( 
IF(priority="P1",1,0)) P1,
sum( 
IF((timediff(delta_ts,creation_ts) > "00:02:00") 
 && (priority="P1") ,1,0))P1_exeeded,
 (select 
 GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT bug_id) 
 from bugs 
 where  
 ( 
   IF((timediff(delta_ts,creation_ts) > "00:02:00") && (priority="P1") 
   && (product_id=237)
   &&(bugs.resolution='FIXED')
   &&(bug_status="RESOLVED")
   &&(bugs.creation_ts >='2013-06-14 09:00:00' 
   && bugs.creation_ts <= '2013-06-16 08:59:59') ,1,0)
 )
) as bug_ids,

SUM(
IF(priority="P2",1,0)) P2,
sum( 
IF((timediff(delta_ts,creation_ts) > "00:01:00") 
&& (priority="P2") ,1,0))P2_exeeded,
(select GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT bug_id) 
 from bugs 
 where
 ( 
 IF((timediff(delta_ts,creation_ts) > "00:02:00") 
 && (priority="P2") 
 && (product_id=237)&&(bugs.resolution='FIXED')
 &&(bug_status="RESOLVED")&&(bugs.creation_ts >='2013-06-14 09:00:00' 
 && bugs.creation_ts <= '2013-06-16 08:59:59') ,1,0)
 )
 ) as bug_ids,
 SUM(
 IF(priority="P3",1,0)) P3count,
 SUM(
 IF(priority="P4",1,0)) P4count 
 from bugs 
 where bugs.product_id=237 
 and bugs.resolution='FIXED' 
 and bugs.creation_ts >='2013-06-14 09:00:00' 
 and bugs.creation_ts <= '2013-06-16 08:59:59' 
 and bug_status="RESOLVED";
```

Result:-

```
+------+------------+---------+------+------------+---------+---------+---------+
| P1   | P1_exeeded | bug_ids | P2   | P2_exeeded | bug_ids | P3count | P4count |
+------+------------+---------+------+------------+---------+---------+---------+
|    7 |          1 | 3743304 |    6 |          1 | 3743305 |       5 |       1 |
+------+------------+---------+------+------------+---------+---------+---------+
```

- For getting the bug ids I used group concat. There comes the complexity to the query

Comment: Index is also your friend, if you find yourself using a lot of columns in your where conditions, create an index and you'll see magic happening ;)

Comment: Agreed with timmied  you have to indexed the tables properly

Comment: can anybody give a simple example ?

Comment: as said, add an index covering all fields used in a where or order by statement. your index may vary, depending on your database engine, but in general this should give improved performance. just be aware that indexes increase your database size, especially big databases might get MUCH bigger if you add many indexes!

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer:-

Solved it like:-

```
select 
sum(
IF(
priority="P1",1,0)) P1, 
sum(
IF(
(timediff(delta_ts,creation_ts) > "00:02:00") && (priority="P1") ,1,0)) P1_exeeded,
REPLACE(GROUP_CONCAT(
IF(
(timediff(delta_ts,creation_ts) > "00:02:00") 
  && (priority="P1") ,bug_id,'')),',,','' ) as bugids,  
SUM(
IF(priority="P2",1,0)) P2, 
sum( IF((timediff(delta_ts,creation_ts) > "00:01:00") 
 && (priority="P2") ,1,0))P2_exeeded,
REPLACE(GROUP_CONCAT(IF((timediff(delta_ts,creation_ts) > "00:02:00") 
 && (priority="P2") ,bug_id,'')),',,','' ) as bugids ,
SUM(
IF(priority="P3",1,0)) P3count, 
sum( 
IF(
(timediff(delta_ts,creation_ts) > "00:02:00") 
&& (priority="P3"),1,0))P3_exeeded,
REPLACE(GROUP_CONCAT(
IF((timediff(delta_ts,creation_ts) > "00:02:00") 
 && (priority="P3") ,bug_id,'')),',,','' ) asbugids, 
SUM(
 IF(priority="P4",1,0)) P4count,
sum(
 IF(
(timediff(delta_ts,creation_ts) > "00:02:00") 
 && (priority="P4") ,1,0)) P4_exeeded,
 REPLACE(
 GROUP_CONCAT(
  IF(
  (timediff(delta_ts,creation_ts) > "00:02:00") 
  && (priority="P4") ,bug_id,'')),',,','' ) as bugids 
  from bugs 
  where bugs.product_id=237 
  and bugs.resolution  ='FIXED' 
  and bugs.creation_ts >='2013-06-14 09:00:00' 
  and bugs.creation_ts <= '2013-06-16 08:59:59' 
  and bug_status="RESOLVED";
```

And I got the result within **0.01sec**

```
+------+------------+-----------+------+------------+---------+---------+------------+--------+---------+------------+--------+
| P1   | P1_exeeded | bugids    | P2   | P2_exeeded | bugids  | P3count | P3_exeeded | bugids | P4count | P4_exeeded | bugids |
+------+------------+-----------+------+------------+---------+---------+------------+--------+---------+------------+--------+
|    7 |          1 | ,3743304, |    6 |          1 | 3743305 |       5 |          0 |        |       1 |          0 |        |
+------+------------+-----------+------+------------+---------+---------+------------+--------+---------+------------+--------+
```

Thank you guys, I used replace, instead of the inner query, and used group con cat, w/o inner query.